# Why is int in C in practice at least a 32 bit type today, despite it being developed on/for the PDP-11, a 16 bit machine?

Tags: c, history

For background, the question is to prepare some training material, which should also should explain a bit why the things are the way they are.

I tried to get some idea of how C began based on [this tutorial](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-tutor.html).

However, this does not give the answer and already has more in the language than I expected.

I learned at university that the first C implementations only had `int`, so there was no need to give a data type and that this is the reason why leaving it out still leads to an integer.

Interestingly there it is explained that `int` can be e.g. 16, 32 or 36 bits, depending on the machine.

First, can one confirm that there was really only int at the beginning and no float/double (I would not be surprised because it was written to have a compiler for UNIX to my understanding).

Second, can one give me a reference how and when it came to be 32 bits for `int`?

Comment: *"I learned at university that the first C implementations only had `int`"* - are you possibly talking about the default type of function arguments, together with the fact that int-returning functions didn't need a forward declaration? Perhaps interacting with the separate fact that some rudimentary hardware only had the `word` type natively in their instruction sets?

Comment: [Related question on Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16351/when-if-ever-was-the-c-language-int-size-altered-from-the-host-machine-word-r)

Comment: IIRC, K&R C had `float` and `double`.  You may be thinking of the predecessor language B.

Comment: @dan04: K&R had floating-point, but the first C may not have: according to [dmr's HOPL2 paper](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) adding `char` to typeless B was only called 'new B', and the first language called C added `struct` and explicit pointer types; while it was already known additional types were needed for FP, since on PDP-11 they weren't (always) the same size, he doesn't say if those types were implemented yet. The bwk link shows they _were_ implemented by 1974.

Comment: The premise of the question is incorrect. C is *not* at least a 32-bit type, neither historically nor now.

Comment: When programming in C for MS-DOS in the 80ies after having programmed in C for UNIX, it became clear that 16 bit integers are simply no fun when your machine has more than 64kB addressable memory space.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types

Comment: @U.Windl 16 bit integers are fine in MS-DOS. It was the 16-bit *pointers* that were a problem, needing all the "near" and "far" model issues. It's also a hassle if the int is not large enough for pointers, which is why intptr_t and ptrdiff_t were (later!) added.

Comment: @pjc: Of course, you could always cast a pointer to a `long` — until LLP64 compilers made this no longer work.

Comment: @pjc50: Use of `near` and `far` pointer types was only a complication if one wanted to *efficiently* access more than 64K of data; suitable use of those types allowed many tasks to be done *more efficiently* than would have been possible with a 32-bit linear model.  For example, if `ptr` was an `int far*` stored in an object of static duration, `*ptr++ = 3;` would require reading all 32 bits of `ptr`, but only require writing back 16 of them.

Comment: @dan04: Yeah that was fun. `intptr_t` didn't exist and `ptrdiff_t` didn't work on DOS unless you had huge model.

Comment: "why leaving it out still leads to an integer." --> Not anymore.  Type needed.

Comment: @dan04 MacOS has a nice feature: if you take a pointer, cast it to an integer type that is too small, and cast it back, it’s _guaranteed_ to crash. First 4GB of logical address space is intentionally unused. Otherwise there would be the risk that an application works until it’s data gets too large.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I think the OP meant "in most real-world implementations of the language". so the premise isn' necessarily wrong. I took the freedom to change the title a bit, should not affect the existing answers.

Comment: @Doc Brown, Torsten Knodt  Even after edit, "Why is int in C in practice at least a 32 bit type today" remains false.  Billions of embedded processors are built each years  C is very popular there.  A significant percentage are 16-bit.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: well, I would not take the title *that* literally (see my former comment about my interpretation) - I wanted to keep my title edit small, without completely changing its meaning. But if you think there are more 16 bit C *compilers* (that's what we count, not processors) in use today than 32 bit C compilers, and you can give us some references, feel free to write an answer.

Comment: @DocBrown It is not a question of more or less compilers using a 16 or 32-bit `int`, it is that "int in C in practice at least a 32 bit type today" discounts any real market for 16-bit `int/unsigned`.  It is not true as 1) the C specifies that minimum size of an `int` is 16 via it range requirements and 2) there exist today many C compilers that use 16-bit `int/unsigned`, especially in the embedded world. ...

Comment: @DocBrown ... [In 2021, the market for 32-bit microcontroller units is forecast to be worth approximately 10.67 billion U.S. dollars worldwide, whilst the market for 16-bit units is set to be worth 3.28 billion U.S. dollars.](https://www.statista.com/statistics/553426/worldwide-microcontroller-unit-market-size/).   Feel free to offer a reference to back up the "least a 32 bit type today" assertion.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: no, I don't offer such a reference - it was not my question, I was just trying to help the OP to express themselves more clearly. But why don't you write an answer? Seriously, it seems you have information we can all learn something from, so why bury it down here in the comment section, where only few people will read it?

Comment: @DocBrown "it was not my question" --> it is the change you made to the question that originated my [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/448256/why-is-int-in-c-in-practice-at-least-a-32-bit-type-today-despite-it-being-devel?noredirect=1#comment989675_448256) to you and OP.  Unfortunately when we try to improve things, sometimes we incur [Did you mess with it](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/419819996486091088/) stickiness. ;-)

Comment: @DocBrown [@pjc50](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/448257/94903) covers my thoughts already.

Comment: C initially not supporting float or double is credible if only for the fact that the IEEE 754 standard for floating point numbers was not established before 1985.

Comment: C models the underlying CPU.  Over the years that has changed quite a bit.

Answer (score 50):

The C standard doesn't specify 32 bits for int, it specifies "at least" 16. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be

In practice, most implementations since the 32-bit machine era picked "int" to be 32 bits, but C implementations for 16 bit machines used 16 bit ints.

"float" appears to also have been in present in K&R C, before the modern standardised ANSI C, so it's been around since the 80s. I can't confirm that the first compiler did not have float.

(An even worse situation is the size of pointers; this has always been implementation-defined, but in the MS-DOS era you could have "near" (16 bit) and "far" (32 bit) pointers and get different answers depending on compiler options)

Comment: I used a compiler that gave you a choice whether int should be 16 or 32 bit. That was around the time where compilers changed from 16 to 32 bit ints, so with this compiler you had the choice. More precisely, the "compiler program" was two different implementations and you can choose which one. I think there are still compilers that let you choose whether plain "char" should behave like signed or unsigned char. (It is always a distinct type).

Comment: @gnasher729 A lot of modern 8 bit compilers still allow you to choose between 16 and 32 bit ints.

Comment: @gnasher729 both GCC and clang allow you to choose signed/unsigned chars.

Comment: Many compilers choose the processor's *word* size for the integer size to make code generation easier.  If the word (processor register) size is less than 16, the compiler will issue code to use 2 byte quantities.   When the C language was developing, microprocessors were standardizing on 8-bits and expanding to 16-bit registers.

Comment: Yeah, the 16-bit PC C compilers (e.g., Borland Turbo C and Microsoft QuickC) used 16-bit `int`.  When 32-bit processors (Intel 386) and 32-operating systems (Linux, Windows NT) got popular, C compilers switched to 32-bit `int`.  However, `int` did not change during the 32- to 64-bit transition, mostly because there wouldn't have been a name for the 32-bit integer type.

Comment: @gnasher729: I think it's a shame that the migration to 64-bit systems wasn't handled as smoothly as the transition to 32-bit systems, with the ability of compilers for 64-bit platforms to treat `long` as either 32 or 64 bits, or a hybrid at the ABI level, recognized as a desirable feature?  Many projects would be more efficient using a 32-bit long, even on 64-bit systems, unless they'll have to use data sets containing billions of elements, but on many such systems at the ABI level reserving 64 bits for every argument is more efficient than packing two 32-bit arguments into every 64 bits.

Comment: @gnasher729: If an ABI specifies that integer arguments will always be either sign- or zero-extended out to 64 bit values, then code compiled to use a 32-bit `long` could call, or called by, code compiled to use a 64-bit `long` and "just work" in cases where the *numerical value* that was passed would be within the range of a 32-bit type.

Comment: @supercat: Well, the problem with the migration is that a lot of existing code had assumed that either (1) `long` is exactly 32 bits, or that (2) a pointer can fit in a `long`.  Microsoft chose to keep #1 and break #2 (LLP64), while GCC chose to keep #2 and break #1 (LP64).

Comment: @dan04: If an ABI promotes all function arguments to 64 bits regardless of integer size, then the question of whether `long` should be `int_least32_t` or `intptr_t` wouldn't need to be decided upon globally, but could largely be handled on a per-module basis, and I would think that on x86-64 such an ABI would generally yield more efficient code generation than the existing one.

Comment: I had a boss who was burned by 16-bit `int` in the early days of Microsoft C/C++.  He insisted we use the `long` type instead, even though that problem ceased to exist about 30 years ago.

Comment: The real problem is the unsigned types. If I had 32 bit long then 32 bit overflow is undefined behaviour, so I avoid it, so as long as I don’t use 4 instead of sizeof(long), 64 bit long shouldn’t create problems. For unsigned long, the result of x+1 when x = 0xffffffff is totally different, so 64 bit unsigned long could break things.

Comment: @gnasher729 I don't understand.  How could x = 0xffffffff if unsigned long is 32 bits?

Comment: @gnasher729: Note that for the first quarter century of C, the semantics of integer overflow were generally recognized as being platform dependent, and the vast majority of platforms defined the semantics as "quiet two's-complement wraparound", which in turn implied that the behavior of `(unsigned)(int1*int2)` would be equivalent to `(unsigned)int1*(unsigned)int2` *except on platforms where behaving in such fashion would be impractical*.  The authors of the Standard didn't mandate it because they never imagined that compilers like gcc might interpret the lack of mandate as inviting deviation.

Comment: @supercat: In hindsight, it would be nice if C provided a standard way to annotate dependence on platform-specific semantics.  So declaring a calculation as `assume(SIGNED_INT_WRAPAROUND)` would enforce the traditional semantics of signed integer overflow, but `assume(NO_INT_OVERFLOW)` would treat it as "undefined behavior".

Comment: I learned C and C++ as a short is 16 bits, a long is 32 bits, and an int is one of those depending on the compiler.

Comment: @davolfman, `long` is 64 bits on some modern implementations, including GCC.  `short` must be at least 16 bits, and it frequently is exactly 16 bits, but it can be wider and sometimes is.  `int` cannot have fewer value bits than `short` or more value bits than `long`, but it doesn't need to be the same size as either one, nor are the choices for its size limited to 16 and 32 bits.  C does not put a fixed upper bound on the sizes of any of these.

Comment: @dan04: There should be at least three choices for many such settings: traditional mode with precise semantics, useful optimizations modes which would uphold some beavioral guarantees even in cases where precise semantics weren't generateed (e.g. guaranteeing that `long long x=int1*int2;` will always without side effects set `x` to some value whose bottom (int_bits) bits match those of the arithmetically correct result, though not necessarily a value within range of `int`), or Gratuitously Clever mode, as processed by a Gratuitously Clever Compiler or a...

Comment: ...Creative Language-Abusing Nonsense Generator, which would interpret the phrase "Undefined Behavior" as an invitation to completely ignore any behavioral precedents that would be applicable to the target platform and application field, and throw the semantics of surrounding code out the window.

Comment: The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) says that there are two architectures (ILP64 and SILP64) were an `int` is 64 bit

Comment: @xanatos: I've worked on SILP64 machines. It's *very* strange to have every integer type (including `short`, and IIRC, even `char`) be 64 bit. Those old Crays didn't even use IEEE-754 standard binary floating point; I remember porting code off them that needed some tweaks because the floating point imprecision trended high on the Crays, and low on IEEE-754 machines, so the same math (with a logical result of `16`) produced `16.000...0001` on a Cray and `15.999...994` on anything else. And oops, the code blindly cast to `int` and then multiplied by `100`, magnifying the error.

Comment: For extra fun in the 8086 world, near and far were often mapped to segment and offset registers, which resulted in 4096 possible combinations of segment and offset that mapped to the same each physical address.

Comment: @rbanffy: In practice, code which made use of address `a:b` would almost never use any segments in the range `a+1` and `a+b/16`.  There were a few situations where code would need to worry about relationships between segment-based and linear addresses, but those mainly involved programming things like the motherboard's DMA controller which used 16 bit addresses along with external circuitry to control the top four bits of the physical address.

Comment: @supercat If it is such a problem, then don't use C compilers with such a feature, or turn off that feature on the C compilers. You can always set -fwrapv on GCC; in fact, just using gcc without any options will usually just work. It's only when the user invokes gcc with -O/-O2/-O3 and without -fwrapv that there's a problem, and it's a bit bizarre to hear Unix C programmers complain that giving a command the wrong arguments leads to it giving unwanted results.

Comment: @prosfilaes: Thing is, compiling with optimization enabled is very common for Release builds, whereas compiling with non-default code-generation options is not.  It would be nice if there were a way to explicitly specify *in the code* (rather than in the Makefile) that `-fwrapv` semantics are required for a particular calculation.  Similar to how you can use `checked` versus `unchecked` to control overflow behavior in C#.

Comment: @prosfilaes It is certainly not the case that you can avoid the issue by not passing flags to the compiler -- it can and will perform some optimizations regardless. And I doubt you can avoid it by switching compilers. Certainly all the mainstream compilers will perform optimizations based on undefined behavior: gcc, clang, msvc, icc... I don't know where you'd find one that doesn't.

Comment: @supercat your “Creative Language-Abusing Nonsense Generator” reminds me on the “DeathStation 9000” (short DS9K). I think, *every* compiler should have such an option, to allow developers to harden their programs against implicit assumptions (or teach them a lesson about the actual possibility to do so).

Comment: @Holger: The notion that such "hardening" is desirable merely serves to define deviancy downward.  The Standard deliberately allows implementations which are specialized for certain tasks great latitude to behave in ways that would make them unsuitable for many other tasks, and the fact that code is not compatible with every imaginable special-purpose implementation should not be viewed as a defect.  Further, armoring code against obtuse compilers would block sanely designed compilers from performing what should be useful optimizations.  If application requirements would be satisfied...

Comment: @GlennWillen GCC doesn't; it produces notoriously naive code when not optimizing. As I said, -fwrapv makes GCC treat signed integers as wrapping, the major undefined behavior people complain about. tcc doesn't perform these operations, and if it were really a big deal, a patch could be made for GCC or Clange to not make these optimizations.

Comment: ...equally well by code as written, or by code with a particular optimizing transform applied, code which is armored to block the useful optimization in order to be compatible with inferior compilers should be recognized as being inferior to code that isn't thus armored, except in situations where compatibility with inferior compilers is required.

Comment: @dan04 I'm curious about your claim that "compiling with non-default code-generation options is not [common]"; certainly if people can't look at the documentation for their compiler, they're not going to find a GCC extension to make certain code wrapping. In standard C, using unsigned integers instead of signed integers usually works.

Comment: @supercat If you don't want to use "inferior" compilers made for the "special-purpose" of making really fast code, then don't. You can write your code in any dialect of any programming language you can compile for or run, and your chosen dialect has at least tcc and gcc -fwrapv to support it. Instead of complaining that your dialect of C is not the default, just use your preferred dialect of C.

Comment: @prosfilaes: The `-fwrapv` and `-fno-strict-aliasing` flags block categories of optimizations that would generally be useful, but are generally not too bad.  What's worse are more subtle optimizing transforms which are unsound but will usually be correct.  For example, if clang or gcc can deduce that some pointer expression `p+i` will be coincidentally equal to some other expression `q`, they will treat them as interchangeable *without blocking downstream transforms that would rely upon the impossibility of any storage being accessed via both `p[i]` and `*q`*.

Comment: @prosfilaes: Which would more often be a useful computation given two `int32_t` values: (1) yield a mathematical integer which will equal the result if it's within the range of `int`, and which is congruent (mod 4294967296) to the result in all cases, or (2) yield the product if within range of `int` and otherwise behave in uselessly unpredictable unreliable fashion that may arbitrarily corrupt memory.  If application requirements would be satisfied by #1, the expression `int1*int2` may often be processed more efficiently than `(int)((unsigned)int1*int2)`.

Comment: @prosfilaes: Special-purpose compilers made for the purpose of generating really fast code *which is suitable only for use in contexts where it will never receive maliciously-generated input*.  The only way to make clang and gcc can generate code that can safely process untrusted input is to block many optimizations that would otherwise be useful *even in such contexts*.  I'd view tasks that need to be sheltered from invalid inputs as being rather "specialized", wouldn't you?

Comment: @supercat Which would be more often a useful computation given c[15] on an array c of 10 elements: providing arbitrary access to an attacker, or terminating the program? This is what I was saying about a Unix C programmer; you could use any number of languages with bounds checking and even overflow checking, languages with minimal to no undefined behavior but instead of you use a language that brags about being fastest, has known foot guns, and complain when the compiler chooses to be fast instead of treat undefined behavior the way you want.

Comment: @supercat The only way to make Clang and GCC generate code that can safely process untrusted input if you can't write standard-perfect C is to use their frontends that compile from Ada, Rust, Go or other languages with things like bounds checking. Strict aliasing was not added to C for special purpose compilers, it was added because Fortran was faster than C because it had strict aliasing, therefore it was added to C to make it go fastest.

Comment: @prosfilaes: Revising that example, given `int a[5][3];`, rank the usefulness of the following ways of reading `a[0[[i]` when `i` is 5: (1) return whatever is in `a[1][2]` at the time; (2) return some arbitrarily-chosen value from among those that `a[1][2]` has hold or will hold within its lifetime; (3) transform code *that wouldn't corrupt memory as written, if processed in either of the above ways* into code that may arbitrarily corrupt memory.

Comment: @Holger: Perhaps an interesting experiment would be to write an emulator for the hypothetical "weirdest" computer that's technically supported by the C standard.  With  things like 11-bit `char` (UTF-EBCDIC encoded), different pointer sizes depending on pointed-to type, and exceptions on signed integer overflow.

Comment: @prosfilaes: *By definition*, if some source code P is accepted by some compiler Q, either P is a conforming C program (though not necessarily a *strictly* conforming one), or Q is not a conforming C implementation.  Further, if there exists a (possibly contrived and useless) program that exercises the Standard's "translation limits" and which an implementation processes correctly, the question of what other programs an implementation can process usefully is left as a Quality of Implementation issue.

Comment: @dan04: If `T` is a source file which exercises the Standard's translation limits, M is a correct machine code implementation thereof, E is any other machine program, and V is a conforming C implementation which targets any platform, one could produce a Deathstation 2000 implementation by testing whether an input source file matches T, executing M if so, testing whether V would accept the program, reproducing V's output if not, and otherwise running E.  The C99 Rationale makes clear that while that would violate the spirit of the Standard, it's consistent with the Standard's intended meaning.

Comment: @prosfilaes: Is there any reason a compiler that seeks to be suitable for tasks other than those involving exclusively sheltered inputs would perform optimizing transforms that are only useful in situations where either (1) nothing that generated code does in response to certain inputs would be viewed as unacceptable, or (2) the optimizer is fed code which it is not designed to process meaningfully, but which it will usually happen to process in a manner meeting application requirements anyhow?

Comment: Note that while C does not specify "at least 32 bits" (only "at least 16"), POSIX does. This makes any implementation that doesn't use at least 32 bits, despite conforming to the C standard itself, incompatible with the only standard for broader OS interfaces on top of C, and thus a non-starter for most purposes (but still plausible for some tiny embedded stuff lke AVR).

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: It's too bad the Committee is unable to recognize that the range of purposes for which the Standard could be useful would be maximized by recognizing features, constructs, and guarantees that implementations should support *when practical*, and providing ways by which programs can ensure that it is rejected by implementations that don't support everything they need.  For many tasks on many smaller platforms, an implementation where `double` is 32 bits or even 24 bits may be more useful than one where operations on `double` require bigger and slower code.

Comment: @supercat: Perhaps they could follow the example of `stdint.h` and define `float_fast16_t` and `float_fast32_t` types.

Comment: @supercat This is starting to sound like a "motte and bailey" argument. Compilers don't generally have optimizations that their authors believed would be useless. They have optimizations that they believe make their compiler more useful, that may at a cost eliminate code that is undefined in their dialect of C.

Comment: @dan04: Calls to variadic functions are required to promote to `double` floating-point arguments of all types other than `long double`, even if nothing in a program would actually need that level of precision.  Given that the Standard has had limits.h since 1989, all that would need to change would be changing requirements on floating-point properties to recommendations, and perhaps requiring that implementations which deviate from recommendations predefine macro `__STDC_UNUSUAL_LIMITATIONS`, so code can refuse to compile on platforms that deviate from common behaviors in unexpected ways.

Comment: @prosfilaes: By your argument, if optimizing transforms would only offer benefits when compilers are used for certain narrow purposes, and would be detrimental to many other purposes, that would suggest that the compiler writers are more interested in making their compilers suitable for those narrow purposes than in making them suitable for general-purpose tasks.  *THAT'S MY POINT*.  My beef with clang and gcc maintainers is that they demand that even programs outside their niche jump through hoops to be compatible with optimizations that will provide no optimizations *to them*.

Comment: @prosfilaes: BTW, how does the Standard characterize actions which the Committee expected general-purpose implementations for commonplace platforms to process in the same fashion that was useful for some tasks, but which they thought implementations *not intended to be suitable for such tasks* might benefit from being allowed to process in a manner inconsistent with sequential program execution: (1) it seeks to define the behavior of *all* such constructs; (2) it seeks to avoid defining the behavior of *any* such constructs.

Comment: @supercat My beef is that people complained about problems with Minix and so produced Linux and complained about Vi and so produced Vim and Nano and complained about FreeBSD and produced NetBSD and OpenBSD. If you don't like using Clang and GCC, stop using them; there are alternatives. Or write a patch for them. Or even use the command line options that do at least 90% of what you want. Stop complaining that compilers that work for many people change their defaults and settings to work for you.

Comment: @prosfilaes: The number of people who would be willing to spend $100-$200 to buy themselves a compiler that works better than clang or gcc is vastly greater than the number of people who would be willing to buy a compiler for everyone might wants to use the code they write.  If the clang and gcc dialects of C were good transpilation targets, one could use a good C transpiler to convert programs to produce gcc/clang-compatible intermediate files that could be distributed along with the source, but clang and gcc semantics aren't a good fit for transpilers.

Comment: @supercat tcc is free. So is gcc -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing, which solves a lot of the problems. You could also write a good C transpiler to Ada (GNAT) or FreePascal.

Comment: @prosfilaes: While `-fwrapv` and `-fno-strict-aliasing` do fix most problems, not all potentially problematic transforms have flags that control them.  For example, given `extern int x[],y[];`, if clang or gcc can determine that some pointer `p` happens to be equal to `x+1`, it will conclude that a write to `*p` cannot possibly affect `y[0]`, even if `p` was formed by taking `y`'s address.  It's would be rare in non-contrived scenarios that clang or gcc would be able to determine that a pointer which is passed the address of `y` would also equal `x+1`, but in cases where `y==x+1` it would...

Comment: ....in general not be possible to prove that a compiler couldn't make such a determination, and use it to conclude that a pointer which is assigned to the address of `y` can't possibly point to `y`.  Even if code happens to work with today's compiler, that would provide no guarantee that tomorrow's won't find new ways to recognize when a pointer might coincidentally equal `x+1`.

Comment: @supercat you seem to be beating around the bush, if you don't like modern C dialects and modern C compilers, you can use a different language with stronger safety guarantees like Ada, Pascal, Rust, etc, without compromising performance. The status quo in Modern C is the result of a 50-year long trajectory, it has all of the optimizations you listed because nearly all developers want them.

Comment: @supercat Then ask for an option to fix that. (I'm pretty sure there's some aliasing trickery there, or this would be a simple bug report.) That would be a way to get a compiler that does what you want, which is not too unreasonable to ask for, instead of demanding that they change everything to fit you.

Comment: @prosfilaes: The problem is that there's a huge gulf between what is necessary to produce a program that will likely work in practice, versus producing a program which is guaranteed to work by design.  What I'm looking for isn't a language where compilers add code to check things like array bounds, but rather one where a compiler can be guaranteed not to analyze a program that guards an array bound in two places, decide each is redundant given the presence of the other, and consequently remove both of them, and where a programmer's omission of a bounds check in a place where...

Comment: ...a machine code wouldn't need one to satisfy application requirements won't result in a compiler deciding it should omit a different bounds check which the programmer had included because it was necessary to meet requirements.

Comment: @supercat It's funny how what you're describing doesn't fit the problems I've heard; it's almost like you're dramatically describing an issue while leaving out what you did to violate the guarantees the C standard gave you. A C program that's likely to work in practice is almost certain to have serious security flaws if connected to the Internet. In any case, for the dozenth time, use TCC or ask for options to turn off optimizations that are causing you problems, don't demand the entire world change to fit you.

Comment: One of the reasons C got its reputation for speed is that it used to uphold the principle that if an application's requirements could be satisfied without performing a certain operation, neither the programmer nor compiler should need to write code to perform that operation.  Unfortunately, when using clang and gcc optimizers, the only way to ensure that machine operations that *are* necessary to satisfy application requirements don't get "optimized out" is often to specify operations in source code that *aren't* necessary at the machine level, and do so in such a way that...

Comment: @prosfilaes: ... will often result in the compiler generating sub-optimal machine code.

Answer (score 8):

My first edition of K&R C defines an 'int' as the natural word length of the machine. Which made sense back then because there were a lot of different word lengths on the machines of the time. Everything from 12 to 36 bits were available.

Comment: Burroughs Large Systems (e.g. model 5900) had 48-bit ints. Right enough, they never had C.

Comment: This stopped being true with 64-bit machines; most 64-bit ABIs use 32-bit `int`.  (Cray being a notable exception, with 64-bit `int`.)  For machines at least 32 bits wide, `long` is often the width of an integer register.  (But not in Windows x64 where only `long long` and pointers are 64-bit.  This is why we now have types like `uintptr_t` and `uint64_t` for use when you don't want to depend on random ABI designers choosing the primitive type widths in a way that's useful for your function or data structure.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think of `int` as being the largest type that's *almost* as efficient as anything smaller.  The definition of "almost" is a bit fuzzy, but on most machines there was a type that was almost twice as fast as anything bigger.  On the 68000, operations on 32-bit values were about 50% slower than on 16-bit values, but on successor platforms they were about the same speed, so 68000 compilers often allowed `int` to be configured as 16 or 32 bits.  On 64-bit machines, CPU-dominated tasks are about the same speed for 32 vs 64, but for memory-dominated tasks, 32-bit types are way faster.

Comment: @PeterCordes That didn't stop being true with 64 bit machines, it was false from the beginning. There are many systems where the natural word length is 8 bit and most instructions can only be done on 8 bit / byte registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Are you sure that's not because x64 really is 32 bit int native? (Look at the instruction encoding.) I remember the early reports being on a 64 bit machine, int is 64 bits (definitely wasn't x64 as that didn't exist yet).

Comment: @Joshua: Yes, the choice of 32-bit `int` is even more obvious on x86-64 than others.  But it was not the first architecture to be extended to 64-bit.  Earlier ones included MIPS-III and I think PowerPC.  Even on DEC Alpha which was designed to be 64-bit from the ground up, `int` was I think still 32-bit in the standard ABI, because the ISA did still provide some opcodes that truncated results to 32-bit, like add.

Comment: @Joshua: I think it's less to do with low-level instruction encoding, and more with the fact that making `int` 64 bits would leave you with only two different integer types (`char` and `short`) to cover three hardware-supported sizes (8, 16, and 32 bits).  Of course, it would be possible to have a platform-specific extra type (e.g., `__int32`) that would be `typedef`ed to `int32_t`, but that's just ugly.

Comment: @dan04: Or you just make int32_t and friends native compiler types.

Answer (score 4):

I'm an old guy and I used 6th Edition Unix around 1974. I believe that's the edition that Dennis Ritchie shared as a result of a conversation in response to Dennis' CACM article of 1972. (This was before the AT&T lawyers got hold of Unix; hilarity ensued when they finally did, but that's a different story.)

My recollection is on the PDP-11/45 at that time, int was 16 bits and long was 32 bits.  Float was 32 bits and double was 64 bits.  They used the native PDP-11 floating point formats from the optional floating point processor (FP11). Ints were automatically widened to 32 bits and floats to 64 bits when passed as arguments to functions.

As they learned to port Unix to other ISAs, the rules on data type sizes had to become more flexible, hence the "int must be at least 16 bits" rule, etc. As a result, <types.h> in standard C has a set of implementation-dependent #defines for things like int32 and uint16 so a developer can portably choose a data type size.  If you really care, you use those definitions.

Comment: The 1974/1975 C Reference Manual documents the existence of machines where `int` was larger than 32 bits, but does not document `long`, suggesting that type hadn't yet been invented.

Comment: Best I can tell, there's no `<types.h>` in the C standard. There *is* a `<sys/types.h>` in POSIX though. An easy mistake to make, but I believe important in this context.

Comment: Starting in C99, fixed-width integer types are defined in [`<stdint.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer), including things like `int32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

C was designed to be maximally portable, and while 8-bit bytes / 16-bit words / 32-bit longwords are common, they aren't universal. There are real-world architectures that use 9-bit bytes and 36-bit words, there are architectures with guard or parity bits that count against the word size but aren't used for representing values, etc.

The language definition only specifies the *minimum range of values* the `int` type must be able to represent; `[-32767..32767]`.  This means an `int` must be *at least* 16 bits wide, but may be wider.  `short` and `long` are similarly specified.  The only type whose size is specified in bits is `char`, which must be *at least* eight bits wide.

`int` is commonly the same size as the native word size, so once 32-bit machines became common, compilers started using 32 bits to represent `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Int wasn’t 16 bit to support PDP/11 but to support a machine popular at the time. Today, we support machines that are popular today. You can get ARM-Cortex 64 bit processors for very little money. So today you want a processor that works well for 64 bit processors.

Int = 16 bit practically forces char=8, short=16, long=32 and long long = 64 bit. On a 64 bit processor you would prefer long = 64 bit.